Rotation of spherical harmonics
I have a question about the rotation of spherical harmonics. In Wikipedia it is mentioned that if we make a rotation in 3D space: $R\vec{r}=\vec{r}'$,then  the Spherical Harmonics can be written as a sum of spherical harmonics in the unrotated basis. To be more precise,
$$
Y_l^m(r')=\sum_{m'=-l}^lD^{(l)}_{mm'}(R)^*Y_l^{m'}(r).  \tag{1}
$$
For $l=1$, and working with Euler's angles $a=c=0$, the $D^{(l)}_{mm'}(R)$ matrix is written in the  following form,
$$
D^1_{m~m'}(0,\beta,0)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{2} (\cos\beta+1) & \frac{\sin\beta}{\sqrt{2}} &
   \frac{1}{2} (1-\cos\beta) \\
 -\frac{\sin\beta}{\sqrt{2}} & \cos\beta & \frac{\sin\beta }{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
 \frac{1}{2} (1-\cos\beta) & -\frac{\sin\beta}{\sqrt{2}} &
   \frac{1}{2} (\cos\beta+1) \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
The spherical harmonics are of the following forms,
$$
Y_1^{\pm1}=\frac{\mp1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2 \pi }} e^{i \pm\varphi } \sin (\theta
   ),\quad 
Y_1^0=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi }} \cos (\theta ) ,
$$
and using some linear combinations
$$
x= 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(\frac{Y_1^{-1}-Y_1^1}{\sqrt{2}}
\right),
\
y= 2i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(\frac{Y_1^{-1}+Y_1^1}{\sqrt{2}}
\right),
\
z=2i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^0.
$$
Using these functions as our basis,
$$x\propto (-1,0,1),y\propto(1,0,1), z\propto (0,1,0).$$
Now, if we make a rotation of $90$ degrees around the y axis, I expect x to become z, and z to become -x, in our new basis. In general, only the $\theta$ angle changes. This is correct, because
$$
D
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}\propto \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow z
\quad
D
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\propto \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow x.
$$
Till now, everything is ok. But when I act with the $D$ operator on the $Y_1^1$ harmonic, something seems wrong,
$$
D\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}\propto
\begin{pmatrix}1\\\sqrt{2}\\1
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\cos{\theta}-i\sin\theta\sin\varphi \tag{2}
$$
The $\theta$ and $\varphi$ variables are mixed.
What is happening?
Could you give me an explanation and perhaps show me another example?

Sperical basis.

What you have written in (2) makes no sense.  Where is the dependence on the rotation angle $b$ or are you assuming $b=\pi/2$?  It seems you are confusing the coordinate angles $\theta, \varphi$ with rotation angles?  Rotating   BTW your $z$ is prop to $Y_1^0$ with no $i$ in there.

I ddin't understand your question. The D(R) matrix depends on the a,b,c angles around the z, y' and z'' axes. And no I do not miz this angles. say that you have something point in the (x,y,z) direction and you change make a rotation around the y axis then we would get (x',y,z'). The  (x',z') would be something of the following form. (x',z')=(Cos[φ]sin[θ+β],Cos[θ+β]). Am i wrong?

You are probably replicating common errors of basis conversion from Cartesian to the spherical basis and back (!),  but it's harder to descend into the error instead of doing it right.
You know from Wikipedia that
$$
2r\sqrt{\pi/3} \begin{bmatrix}{Y^1_1\\ Y^0_1 \\ Y^{-1}_1}\end{bmatrix} = {\mathbf U}  \begin{bmatrix}{x\\ y\\  z}\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
{\mathbf U} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/\sqrt{2} & -i/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1/\sqrt{2} & -i/\sqrt{2} & 0 
\end{pmatrix},  \qquad {\mathbf U}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ i/\sqrt{2} & 0 &i/\sqrt{2}\\ 
 0&1&0 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so that you need to compute
$$
{\mathbf U}^{-1} D^1(0,\pi/2,0)  {\mathbf U}= {\mathbf U}^{-1}  \tfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
1&\sqrt{2} & 1  \\ 
 -\sqrt{2} &0& \sqrt{2} \\
1&  -\sqrt{2} &1
\end{pmatrix}   {\mathbf U} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0&0 & -1  \\ 0& 1& 0   \\
1&   0 &0
\end{pmatrix} ,
$$
which sends $(x,y,z) \mapsto (-z,y,x)$.
For another example, consider $\beta =\pi$,
$$
{\mathbf U}^{-1} ~D^1(0,\pi,0) ~ {\mathbf U}= \operatorname{(-1,1,-1)},
$$
sending $(x,y,z) \mapsto (-x,y,-z)$.

Very clear, very nice.  But what is "WP"?
